# VsTemplate: Usage of TemplateGroupID

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-templates

No matter which ID from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Projects\` I use, none of them works! When I set `ShowByDefault` to `false`, nothing will be shown in the "Add New Item" window.
In my example I use `SharePointItemTemplateGroupID`, but also `Web` does not work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**My *.vstemplate:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate-sdkextension/2010">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>My User Control</Name>
    <Description>My User Control with My-specific content.</Description>
    <Icon>MyUserControl.ico</Icon>
    <TemplateID>b83fe377-e03a-40a8-9366-a04988fae2a7</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>MyUserControl.ascx</DefaultName>
    <TemplateGroupID>SharePointItemTemplateGroupID</TemplateGroupID>
    <ProjectSubType>SharePointItemTemplateGroupID</ProjectSubType>
    <ShowByDefault>true</ShowByDefault>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Web</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.$fileinputextension$">MyUserControl.ascx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.$fileinputextension$.cs">MyUserControl.ascx.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.$fileinputextension$.designer.cs">MyUserControl.ascx.designer.cs</ProjectItem>
    <CustomParameters>
      <CustomParameter Name="MappedFolderType" Value="UserControl" />
      <CustomParameter Name="$UC$" Value="UserControl" />
      <CustomParameter Name="$baseclass$" Value="UserControl"/>
    </CustomParameters>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectExtensions.Wizards, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectExtensions.Wizards.GenericMappedFolderWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about registry keys, but if you want your project template to show up in a certain folder of the New Project dialog, place it in a corresponding folder on the file system. For example, place your zipped template file here:

`C:\Users\<yourusername>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\SharePoint\`

The `CSharp` folder is the language folder, so substitute `Visual Basic` or whatever language you require. Also, the `SharePoint` folder won't exist at the above path, so you'll have to create it. The contents of this folder is merged with the installed folder at:

`\VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\`

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This is still useful... I kept thinking that the "ProjectSubType" property in the .vstemplate file is what would help me get it to appear under an existing category under "Visual C# Items" in the Add New Item dialog, e.g. "Code" - still don't know what ProjectSubType actually does or where it appears but your answer helped me get my item template where I wanted it to show up, thanks!